# APT update automation via Bash script

Tags: apt, bash, scripts, automation

I am relatively new to Linux in general, still learning :)

I want to write a bash script for automation of `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. I have the idea of sending the `apt update` command, then watching the lines for specific words.

E.g, after `apt update` was done, it says:

```
 Reading state information... Done
 89 packages can be upgraded.
```

So in this case I want to look for `can be upgraded`. If those words are in the output the script shall execute `apt upgrade -y`.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this tool `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` giving simple output.

The `--human-readable` flag gives more information.

In short, `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable` gives two numbers :

```
<n1> packages can be updated.
<n2> updates are security updates.
```

`/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` with no option has this output layout:

```
<n1>;<n1>
```

So it is possible to extract the first number and if it is greater than 0, say that some update is available.

Extract the first number, number of available updates:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check |& cut -d";" -f 1
```

Use it in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check |& cut -d";" -f 1) -gt 0 ]; then
    # Some commands
    sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
fi
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much for the quick help :)

Comment: This is working for me really well.

But I have another question: I found out that sometimes, when I use "apt list --upgradeable" it tells me, that there are some packages that can be updated, but when I run "/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check |& cut -d";" -f 1", the output is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

In practice you don't care... Just run

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

in sequence, if there is nothing to upgrade, nothing will happen. This is a script, and this is the computer doing the work, running `apt upgrade` isn't going to take much CPU.

The only tests worth doing here is that `apt-update` and `apt-upgrade` ran properly (no network errors, no half-installed/misconfigured packages).